# Selecting rows by last 3 characters in a column with strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
      name               year ...
0     Carlos - xyz       2019
1     Marcos - yws       2031
3     Fran - xxz         2431
4     Matt - yre         1985
...
```

I want to create a new column, called type.
If the name of the person ends with "xyz" or "xxz" I want type to be "big"

So, it should look like this:

```
      name               year   type
0     Carlos - xyz       2019    big
1     Marcos - yws       2031  
3     Fran - xxz         2431    big
4     Matt - yre         1985
...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @jpp it worked as well! thanks a lot for being so nice and helping me here!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
Use `str.contains` to generate a mask:

```
m = df.name.str.contains(r'x[yx]z$')
```

Or,

```
sub_str = ['xyz', 'xxz']
m = df.name.str.contains(r'{}$'.format('|'.join(sub_str)))
```

Now, you may either create your column with `np.where`,

```
df['type'] = np.where(m, 'big', '')
```

Or, `loc` in place of `np.where`;

```
df['type'] = ''
df.loc[m, 'type'] = 'big'
```

```
df
           name  year type
0  Carlos - xyz  2019  big
1  Marcos - yws  2031     
3    Fran - xxz  2431  big
4    Matt - yre  1985
```

---

**Option 2**
As an alternative, consider `str.endswith` + `np.logical_or.reduce`

```
sub_str = ['xyz', 'xxz']
m = np.logical_or.reduce([df.name.str.endswith(s) for s in sub_str])

df['type'] = ''
df.loc[m, 'type'] = 'big'
```

```
df
           name  year type
0  Carlos - xyz  2019  big
1  Marcos - yws  2031     
3    Fran - xxz  2431  big
4    Matt - yre  1985
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED could we do that using an "or" or "|" ? I've just used xyz and xxz as example, I'd like to try avoiding regex

Comment: @abutremutante Yes, there should be a method with `np.logical_or.reduce`, I'l type it up for you in a sec.

Comment: @COLDSPEED would "endswith" apply in this case?

Comment: @abutremutante I have fixed option 1 as well as given you another option 2. Yes, endswith will apply for that.

Comment: I preferred to use multiple df.loc[df.name.str.endswith('xxx'), 'type'] = 'big' to keep it simple but it worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using [`pandas.Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.html).

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Carlos - xyz', 2019], ['Marcos - yws', 2031],
                   ['Fran - xxz', 2431], ['Matt - yre', 1985]],
                  columns=['name', 'year'])

df['type'] = np.where(df['name'].str[-3:].isin({'xyz', 'xxz'}), 'big', '')
```

Alternatively, you can use `.loc` accessor instead of `numpy.where`:

```
df['type'] = ''
df.loc[df['name'].str[-3:].isin({'xyz', 'xxz'}), 'type'] = 'big'
```

**Result**

```
           name  year type
0  Carlos - xyz  2019  big
1  Marcos - yws  2031     
2    Fran - xxz  2431  big
3    Matt - yre  1985
```

**Explanation**

- Extract last 3 letters using `pd.Series.str`.
- Compare to a specified `set` of values for O(1) complexity lookup.
- Use `numpy.where` to perform conditional assignment for new series.